# MATLAB: Moving Integrator (Sum) Window with Varying Size, Based on a Condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cumsum

I'd like to define the start and end indices of a moving integrator (sum) window based on the cumulative sum of the values of `array`. Each window should have a cumulative sum of less than or equal to a threshold.

The `end_index` of this window is uniformly moving forward by 1 for the future windows, however the `start_index` is dependent on the values of `array`. `start_index` could move forward, stay the same or backwards (negative values), hence the size of this moving window is not fixed.

For example:

`array = [ 1 0 2 1 1 2 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 1]`;

With the `start_index = 1`, the cumulative sum of `array` will be 5 at `end_index = 5`, for the first window.

Now for the next window, the `end_index` is moved forward by 1 such that the new `end_index = 6`. I'd like to know how I could find the new `start_index` by back calculating the cumulative sum from the new `end_index` so that `cumsum` is less than or equal to 5 for the new window as well. In this case, the new `start_index = 4`.

Any suggestions on how it could be done?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean by "... and I'd like to back calculate to find the new `start_index`...".  Can you show a numerical example?

Comment: rayryeng, sorry the description wasn't very clear. The `Summ` is a forward cumulative summation of `array` for the first case. Once I find the `end_index` once, then I'd like to back calculate the `Summ` of `array` to get a cumulative of 5, in this case, the new `start_index` will be 4.

Comment: First window: sum(array(1:5)) = 5; Second window: sum(array(4:6)) = 4 (less than or equal to 5)

Comment: This is similar to a moving integrator window without a fixed length. Only the end index is uniformly moving forward.

Comment: You lost me when you changed `end_index = 6`. Why is the new `start_index = 4`? The cumulative difference `Summ(6) - Summ(3) == 4` which is less than your threshold, so why do we change `start_index` to `4` and not `3`?

Comment: breaker, `Summ` mentioned above is the forward cumulative sum of `array` for the first window only. After the first window is defined, the cumulative sum should count backwards from the next `end_index`.

Comment: In this example, I'm trying to define windows with cumulative sums of 5 or less of `array`. Initially, the `start_index` is 1 and `end_index` is 5 (1+0+2+1+1 = 5). Next I'm moving my `end_index` forward by 1, so the next `end_index` will be 6. Now I should be counting backward to find in which index the cumulative sum will be less than or equal to 5, and that will be index 4 (2+1+1 = 4) which will be my new `start_index`. (with a `start_index` of 3, `cumsum` backward from index 6 will be 6, which is larger than 5).

Comment: So this moving qualification window does not have a fixed length but the `end_index` moves uniformly forward by 1 for the future windows, but the `start_index` could move forward or backward or remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that if we want to get cumulative sum from an starting index `k` there is no need again to compute cumsum. Instead only cumsum computed onec, and disired cumulative sum is difference of original cumulative sum and `k-1`th element of original cumulative sum

```
original_Summ = [1 1 3 4 5 7 7 7 8 10 10 11 11 12 13]
k=3
new_Summ = original_Summ - original_Summ(k-1)
```

Note: following implementation may cause memory limits if size of `array` is lage. Instead each cmp and cmp1 sould be compted in each iteration.

```
array = [ 1 0 2 1 1 2 0 0 1  2 0  1  0  1  1 ];
%forward cumsum
fwd = cumsum(array);
%backward cumsum
bkw = cumsum(array(end:-1:1));%cumsum(array,'reverse')
%difference of cumulative sum with all starting indices
cmp = bsxfun(@minus,fwd,[0 fwd(1:end-1)].');%in matlab r2016b cmp= fwd-[0 fwd(1:end-1)].'
cmp1= bsxfun(@minus,bkw,[0 bkw(1:end-1)].');%in matlab r2016b cmp1=bkw-[0 bkw(1:end-1)].'
%find last indices of elements  that are <=5
[r, c] = find(cmp <=5);
idx = accumarray(r,c,[],@max);
[r1, c1] = find(cmp1 <=5);
idx1 = accumarray(r1,c1,[],@max);
idx1 =flipud(numel(array) + 1-idx1);
%loop to find indices from previous indices
si = 1;
index={};
while true
    ei = idx(si);
    if ei == numel(array)
        break;
    end
    index {end+1} = [si,ei];
    ei = ei+1;
    si = idx1(ei);
    index {end+1} = [si,ei];
end
disp(index)
```

Comment: rahnema1, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much. 

The output of the `index` of your code here will be: 
[`start_index`, `end_index`] = [1,5],[4,6],[4,9], etc ... 
However, I'd like to also include the indices for when `end_index` value is 0 such that:[`start_index`, `end_index`] = [1,5],[4,6],[4,7],[4,8],[4,9], etc ... since I'll need each window length info as well. How could this be done?

Comment: @BehnazEnsan You possibly want [1, 2],[1,5][4 ,6]... since second element is 0 ? if it possible please add more clarification to your question and add your expected output to the question

Comment: the window with [start_index, end_index] = [1,2] won't have a cumulative sum of 5. I guess I want it to count up until it exceeds 5, then it'll  save the index before exceeding 5.

Comment: @BehnazEnsan Thanks for accepting the answer. but I do not know how to add indices of 0s and exclude [0,2]

Answer (score 0):

To find the end_index for any given start_index:

```
start_index = 2;
threshold = 20;

if(sum(start_index:end)<threshold) %Error checking
    end_index = -1; 
else 
    end_index = find(cumsum(array(start_index:end)) >= threshold,1) + start_index - 1;
end
```

To find the start_index for any given end_index:

```
end_index = 6;
threshold = 20;

if(sum(1:end_index)<threshold) %Error checking
    start_index = -1; 
else
    start_index = end_index + 1 - find(cumsum(fliplr(array(1:end_index))) >= threshold,1);

end %Error checking
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ian, I changed the array and threshold for a simpler example. In this case, the new `start_index` should be 4. Back calculating the sum from index 6 to 4 will output 4 which is less than or equal to 5 (new threshold). Your code here outputs `start_index` = 3 though.

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest `start_index` such that `sum(array(start_index:end_index)) >= threshold`, or the smallest such that  `sum(array(start_index:end_index)) >= threshold`? [Still a little unclear to me] Since the two will be next to each other, you can just add one to my outputted `end_index` if you're looking for the latter. (`start_index = end_index + 2 - find(cumsum(fliplr(array(1:end_index))) >= threshold,1);`)